# Best sites for ASP.NET MVC RC Refresh Documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out how to use ASP.NET MVC and it seems the only way to learn it is through reading blog posts.  Scott Gu and Phil Haak are the two that come to mind.  The problem I am running into is that alot of the documentation they write is relevant at the time and doesn't work in the latest versions.

Is there a place that has the documentation for RC only?  What are the best places to look for documentation on MVC RC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this helps: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/a-guide-to-learning-asp.net-mvc-release-candidate-1.aspx

Comment: Is there still no official MSDN documentation out yet?